# Trying to find if certain text exists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im trying to see if the text "Nationally registered" exists on the profile pages on a website i am scraping. Its right after the text "Licensed to work in: " ... if it contains the text i will write their license type into a csv file as "Nationally registered" and if that text does not exist i will write "state" for the license in the csv file...thats the problem/coding logic im using

Heres the link to the profile page i am testing my code out on
https://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zackdisinger/

it keeps printing false... below is my code that im trying

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#Chrome webdriver filepath...Chromedriver version 74
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mfoytlin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
page = driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zackdisinger/')
time.sleep(2)
show_more_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zsg-wrapper-footer').click()
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


if soup.find(text='Nationally registered'):
    print('Success')
else:
    print('False')
```

Comment: can you share the exact error that it gives for text doesn't exists or whatever

Comment: where does the text exist at on that url that you linked. I did a find... in google chrome searching for 'registered' and no hits.

Comment: It prints false no matter what is there @Ankit Agrawal

Comment: You have to click the show more button on the page to see the licensing @probat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression `re` to check the text exist or not.Here is your code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

#Chrome webdriver filepath...Chromedriver version 74
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mfoytlin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
page = driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zackdisinger/')
show_more_button =WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'Show')][contains(.,'more')]")))
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", show_more_button)
show_more_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


if soup.find(text=re.compile('Nationally registered')):
    print('Success')
else:
    print('False')
```

It is printing success on console.

```
Success
```

Answer (score 2):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains to check for p tag containing that string. I've given True/False though easy to adapt to Success/False

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Chrome webdriver filepath...Chromedriver version 74
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mfoytlin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
page = driver.get('https://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zackdisinger/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".zsg-wrapper-footer a"))).click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select_one('p:contains("Nationally registered")')
print(data is not None)
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded through AJAX from different URL:

```
import re
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/lender-profile/zackdisinger/'
screen_name = [i for i in url.split('/') if i][-1]
r = requests.get(url).text

url_json = 'https://mortgageapi.zillow.com/getRegisteredLender?partnerId=' + re.search(r'"partnerId":"(.*?)"', r).group(1)
payload = {"fields":["aboutMe","address","cellPhone","contactLenderFormDisclaimer","companyName","employerMemberFDIC","employerScreenName","equalHousingLogo","faxPhone","hideCellPhone","imageId","individualName","languagesSpoken","memberFDIC","nationallyRegistered","nmlsId","nmlsType","officePhone","rating","screenName","stateLicenses","stateSponsorships","title","totalReviews","website"],"lenderRef":{"screenName":screen_name}}
data = requests.post(url_json, json=payload).json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print()
print('Is nationally registered =', data['lender']['nationallyRegistered'])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "lender": {
        "aboutMe": "From day one I provide the utmost relational-based experience to make you feel comfortable with your home financing decisions.\n\nEmpowerment and integrity is key to successfully making a home loan a smooth process from start to finish. Acquiring a mortgage in today's market takes product knowledge and underwriting know how. Every client has their own story, their own future. I am here to match today's mortgages to clients dreams of home-ownership.\n",
        "address": {
            "address": "10412 Allisonville Rd Suite 50",
            "city": "Fishers",
            "stateAbbreviation": "IN",
            "zipCode": "46038"
        },
        "companyName": "Bank of England Mortgage",
        "employerMemberFDIC": true,
        "employerScreenName": "BoEMortgage",
        "equalHousingLogo": "EqualHousingLender",
        "faxPhone": {
            "areaCode": "317",
            "number": "3754",
            "prefix": "536"
        },
        "id": "ZU101hnzx7ntuyx_8z2sb",
        "imageId": "2910837992a9cc44d31c26bd7532d2dd",
        "individualName": {
            "firstName": "Zachary",
            "lastName": "Disinger"
        },
        "languagesSpoken": [],
        "nationallyRegistered": true,
        "nmlsId": 1053091,
        "nmlsType": "Individual",
        "officePhone": {
            "areaCode": "317",
            "number": "0416",
            "prefix": "252"
        },
        "rating": 5.0,
        "screenName": "zackdisinger",
        "stateLicenses": {},
        "stateSponsorships": {},
        "title": "Mortgage Banker",
        "totalReviews": 120,
        "website": "http://boeindy.com"
    }
}

Is nationally registered = True
```

Comment: json looks like a foreign language to me as i am just starting and am only familiar with bs4 and selenium... any links/recommendations to get started/familiar with using this method? @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @mcfoyt It's not about JSON. Just observer where is the page making request, either through Firefox of Chrome developer tools for example.

Answer (score 0):

try the conditional block like this,

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Nationally registered')]").isDisplayed())
{
 print('Success')
}
else {
print ('False')
}
```